# How to output odd and even rows in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project where I'm pulling posts from the database and rendering on the home page view. Like a Blog. (On the home page I limit this to 3 posts)

I have 6 rows in the table, and would like to style the output based on ODD and Even rows.

**Here is my controller:**

```
public function index()
{
   $counter = Post::count();
   $posts= DB::table('posts')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(3)->get();

    return view('home',compact('posts','counter')); 
}
```

I want the even numbered rows to have `<div class="even">` and the odd numbered rows to have `<div class="odd">`

When I `dd` on `$counter` I get the value 6. This is correct. I have 6 rows in the table.

What I'm currently trying based on other articles I've found:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
@if($counter % 2 == 0)
<div class="even">{{$post->title}}</div>
@else
<div class="odd">{{$post->title}}</div>
@endif
```

This doesn't do anything. Still outputs the rows as 6,5,4,3,2,1

So how can I write the IF Statement inside my Foreach loop to say...

```
if ($counter == odd)
<div class="odd">
else
<div class="even">
```

The order I'm looking for is:

- Odd
- Even
- Odd
- Even

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$counter` is a static variable, so calling `$counter % 2 == 0` will always show the same result.

**If you are using Laravel 5.4+**, there is a `$loop` variable included in the `@foreach()`. So you can access your mod division within the loop.

**Here is the example for Laravel 5.4+**

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @if($loop->iteration % 2 == 0)
        <div class="even">{{$post->title}}</div>
    @else
        <div class="odd">{{$post->title}}</div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm using 5.7  Had no idea about the $loop variable. This worked great. In this case `$counter` wouldn't be needed then, correct?

Comment: That is correct, $loop should be able to handle it. I upgraded to 5.4 when I found out about the `$loop` thing. Comes in handy so often.

Comment: style="background:{{ $loop->iteration % 2 == 0 ? '#FEFEFE' : '#FFF' }}"

Answer (score 24):

**Laravel 5.8.5  add even and odd Boolean flags in the Blade loop variable**

Now you can use:

> $loop->even  or  $loop->odd

Instead of

> $loop->iteration % 2

[Reference link](https://www.magutti.com/blog/blade-odd-even-loop-method)

Answer (score 4):

You need to increment the counter on each iteration.

```
@php
  $counter = 1;
@endphp

@foreach ($posts as $post)
  @if($counter % 2 == 0)
   <div class="even">{{$post->title}}</div>
  @else
   <div class="odd">{{$post->title}}</div>
  @endif
  @php 
   $counter++;
  @endphp
@endforeach
```

Comment: This works as well, but the $loop variable seems a little cleaner IMO. Thanks for the help.